# Adding labels to time series grouped by year line plot over the lines - Matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

It is driving me crazy that I can't accomplish something that should be simple enough. I have a time series that I grouped by year so that I can plot each year and compare them. When I plot I have 21 lines, so instead of a legend box I'd like to add the year to the end of each line, like this graph here (example): 
[image: line plot with several lines]

I've created a function to take any time series and return this plot, and I'm struggling to add this custom label/annotation.

My code is this:

```
def plot_by_year(ts):
# first I group the time series (ts) by year:
 year_group = ts.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq ='A'))
 yearly = pd.DataFrame()
 for year, group in year_group:
     yearly[year.year] = group.values.ravel()

# now to plot it, the easy mode is:
 yearly.plot(figsize = (12,14), legend=True)
 plt.gca().legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5));
```

However, this only gives me a legend box outside the plot (see plot below)

[image: line plot]

The alternative I'm trying, following [this instructions](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/28/how-to-make-beautiful-data-visualizations-in-python-with-matplotlib/) is this:

```
   for rank, column in enumerate(years):
       plt.plot(np.arange(0,13), yearly[column].values, lw=2.5)
       y_pos = yearly[column].values[-1] - 0.5
       plt.text(12, y_pos, rank)
```

This gives me `KeyError: 1996`, which is the first year of my data. I've tried so many things that I don't even know anymore what I'm doing. Help!

Comment: What is `years`? Are you sure it is the same data type as your column names? i.e. the difference between `yearly["1996"]` and `yearly[1996]`?

Comment: oh, I forgot to add, years is a range with the years that correspond to the columns (the time range of my data):

```years = np.arange(1996,2018)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `years` isn't the same as `yearly.columns`. Maybe you just got the datatypes wrong (ints vs strings?). Try this instead:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # probably unnecessary tbh but I prefer working with the ax obj rather than plt
n_points = yearly.shape[0]  # generalize out that 12. This is the number of points in your series. If it's months then I guess it's always 12...
for year in yearly:  # get the column names straight off the dataframe
    ax.plot(np.arange(n_points), yearly[year].values, lw=2.5)
    y_pos = yearly[year].values[-1] - 0.5
    ax.text(n_points, y_pos, year) # You wanted to label it with the column name, not the column index which is what rank would have given you
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! And yes, I wasn't getting the correct datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Pandas to do plotting. That interface is a little different from what I am about to describe below but is a rough tutorial

```
 # The following creates a new figure of desired size and 2 subplots
 f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(9,3))

 # the following is a Pandas DataFrame. It doesn't matter how you got it
 df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', sep=r'\s+')

 # here is a plot:
 ax[0].plot(df['x'], np.abs(df['y'])/1000, 
         label="whatever I want")
 ax[1].plot(df['x'], np.abs(df['g'])/1000, 
         label="another  whatever I want")
 # set whatever I want for the labels
 ax[0].set_ylabel("My x-label")
 ax[1].set_ylabel("My Y-label") 

 # the bbox argument controls where the legend is located
 #  bbox_to_anchor=(0.4, .5) for example is inside
 f.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5))
```

Comment: The question isn't about making a legend but about making text annotations positioned at the last data point of each series i.e. like the for loop at the end of the question